# Also changing the alternative HTML5 video file/format source via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm still not really 'good' with Javascript and jQuery but I'm learning. The following, however, puzzles me:

I have a standard HTML5 video tag:

```
  <video id="videoclip">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
```

Now I need to change to video src via jQuery. If I only have ONE source i.e.

```
    <source id="mp4" src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

I just do THIS:

```
function changeVideo() {

        var newVideo = "new_video.mp4";

        $("#videoclip").attr("src",newVideo) }
```

(I abbreviated this snippet. I actually have quite a few variables and things that happen set up there).

So this works well. But what do I need to do if I have TWO sources as in the very first code segment? An alternative webm file?

I tried giving the two source tags different IDs like so:

```
   <source id="mp4" src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source id="webm" src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
```

and then did this:

```
function changeVideo() {

        var newVideo = "new_video.mp4";
        var newVideo2 = "new_video.webm";

        $("#mp4").attr("src",newVideo);
        $("#webm").attr("src",newVideo2)
```

Doesn't work. I mean it DOES the first time I play the video but when I use another similar function to change the sources yet again it won't work. It will be the same source set in the first place. It won't budge. :(

Everything I wrote over the last hours works perfectly now with this exception.

How do I get past this exception?

Comment: Do you want a selection of videos from a dropdownlist ? And by selection a particular video will play its content..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this in the `changeVideo` function:

```
$("#videoclip")[0].load();

$("#videoclip")[0].play();
```

Comment: You do not need to call `play`. Only if the video has stopped before.